# What does the App Service Url under output in VSTS mean and do?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, release

I'm trying to understand what the App Service Url part of the Output Section of a VSTS Deployment is.

[image: Release Deploy Task]

When you hover over the (i) it says:

> Specify a name for the output variable that is generated for the URL
>   of the Azure App Service. The variable can be consumed in subsequent
>   tasks.

This gives me the impression that I am putting the name of a variable I want the Url of the app service assigned to.

Looking at other websites, they are putting the url of the website in.

I'm not sure how to be using it in subsequent steps.  Can anyone help?

[image: AppServiceUrl]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This variable is used for exactly what you think it would be used for. When you deploy to your App Service, you may want to use the App Service URL for a subsequent release task step.

You should create a variable as similar to hold the output URL:

[image]

You can then use it in a subsequent release step as shown below. (Note: I am simply using the Command Line release task to simulate how to use the output variable).

[image]

Here I have used the output URL of my Azure App Service as a command line argument in a subsequent release step.